# What is the difference between the add and offer methods in a Queue in Java?

Tags: java, queue, addition

Take the `PriorityQueue` for example http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#offer(E)

Can anyone give me an example of a [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) where the [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add-E-) and [`offer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer-E-) methods are different?

According to the [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) doc, the `add` method will often seek to ensure that an element exists within the `Collection` rather than adding duplicates. So my question is, what is the difference between the `add` and `offer` methods?

Is it that the `offer` method will add duplicates regardless? (I doubt that it is because if a `Collection` should only have distinct elements this would circumvent that).

EDIT:
In a `PriorityQueue` the `add` and `offer` methods are the same method (see my answer below). Can anyone give me an example of a class where the `add` and `offer` methods are different?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I guess the difference is in the contract, that when element can not be added to collection the `add` method throws an exception and `offer` doesn't.

From: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29

> If a collection refuses to add a
>   particular element for any reason
>   other than that it already contains
>   the element, it **must throw** an
>   exception (rather than returning
>   false). This preserves the invariant
>   that a collection always contains the
>   specified element after this call
>   returns.

From: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer%28E%29

> Inserts the specified element into
>   this queue, if possible. When using
>   queues that may impose insertion
>   restrictions (for example capacity
>   bounds), method offer is generally
>   preferable to method
>   Collection.add(E), which can fail to
>   insert an element only by throwing an
>   exception.

Comment: +1 for finding that snippet about when to use `offer` vs `add`.

Answer (score 42):

The short answer: **it depends** on the concrete implementation.

If your queue has a max capacity limit, there actually is a difference.

- Case #1 (**no max capacity limit**) applied:

There is **no difference** like the implementation of [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return offer(e);
}
```

---

- Case #2 (**max capacity limit**) applied:

**There actually is a difference** like the implementation of [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) which extends [`AbstractQueue`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html) :

```
// ArrayBlockingQueue which extends AbstractQueue
public boolean add(E e) {
    return super.add(e);
}

// AbstractQueue
public boolean add(E e) {
    if (offer(e))
        return true;
    else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Queue full");
}
```

- `offer`: if the queue is full, return `false` and will not throw an exception
- `add`: if the queue is full, throw an exception

Comment: I know, I just posted that answer myself a few minutes ago. Do you know of any classes where the `add` method is different to the `offer` method?

Answer (score 23):

The difference is following:

- **offer** method - tries to add an element to a queue, and returns ***false*** if the element can't be added (like in case when a queue is full), or ***true*** if the element was added, and doesn't throw any specific exception.
- **add** method - tries to add an element to a queue, returns ***true*** if the element was added, or throws an IllegalStateException if no space is currently available.

Comment: add method never returns false if the element is already available

 Queue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<>();
        String b="java";
        boolean is1 = q.add(b);
        boolean is2 = q.add("java");
        boolean is3 = q.add(b);
        boolean is4 = q.offer("java");
        boolean is5 = q.offer(b);
        boolean is6 = q.offer(b);
        System.out.println("qq::"+q);

Comment: Thanks, Raj! I've updated my response above. Oracle documentation says: "The offer method inserts an element if possible, otherwise returning false. This differs from the Collection.add method, which can fail to add an element only by throwing an unchecked exception. The offer method is designed for use when failure is a normal, rather than exceptional occurrence, for example, in fixed-capacity (or "bounded") queues."

Answer (score 20):

The difference between `offer` and `add` is explained by these two excerpts from the javadocs:

From the [`Collection`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) interface:

> If a collection refuses to `add` a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns.

From the [`Queue`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer(E)) interface

> When using queues that may impose insertion restrictions (for example capacity bounds), method `offer` is generally preferable to method `Collection.add(E)`, which can fail to insert an element only by throwing an exception.

`PriorityQueue` is a `Queue` implementation that does not impose any insertion restrictions.  Therefore the `add` and `offer` methods have the same semantics.

By contrast, `ArrayBlockingQueue` is an implementation in which `offer` and `add` behave differently, depending on how the queue was instantiated.

Answer (score 11):

The `Queue` interface specifies that `add()` will throw an `IllegalStateException` if no space is currently available (and otherwise return `true`) while `offer()` will return `false` if the element couldn't be inserted due to capacity restrictions.

The reason they are the same in a `PriorityQueue` is that this queue is specified to be unbounded, i.e. there are no capacity restrictions.  In the case of no capacity restrictions, the contracts of `add()` and `offer()` display the same behaviour.

Answer (score 9):

I will write the java contract example code for the `offer` method and the `add` method showing how they differ.

```
BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);
queue.add("TestQuue1");  // will return true        
queue.add("TestQuue2");  // will return true
queue.add("TestQuue3");  // will throw "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full

BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);
queue.offer("TestQuue1"); // will return true       
queue.offer("TestQuue2"); // will return true   
queue.offer("TestQuue3"); // will return false and will not throw any exception
```

Answer (score 8):

from the source code in jdk 7 as follow:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    if (offer(e))
        return true;
    else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Queue full");
}
```

we can easily know that the add function will return true when successfully add a new element into the queue, but throw a exception when failed .

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

The offer method inserts an element if possible, otherwise returning false. This differs from the Collection.add method, which can fail to add an element only by throwing an unchecked exception. The offer method is designed for use when failure is a normal, rather than exceptional occurrence, for example, in fixed-capacity (or "bounded") queues.

Answer (score 1):

**offer** method throws true or false, if addition is done

**add** method throws an exception when no addition possible in queue

Answer (score 0):

- In Java, the Queue interface provides two methods for adding elements
  to the queue: **`add(E e)`** and **`offer(E e)`**.

Both methods add the specified element to the queue if it is possible to do so immediately without violating capacity restrictions. However, there is a difference in behavior:

**add(E e)**: This method throws an `IllegalStateException` if the element cannot be added at this time due to capacity restrictions.

**offer(E e)**: This method returns `false` if the element cannot be added due to capacity restrictions, otherwise it adds the element and returns `true`.

Here's a small example to illustrate the difference:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class QueueExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        int capacity = 2; // Set capacity to 2

    // add elements 1 to 3 to the queue
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        // add() method
        if (queue.size() < capacity) {
            System.out.println("Adding " + i + " using add(): " + queue.add(i));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Capacity reached. Cannot add " + i + " using add()");
        }

        // offer() method
        System.out.println("Adding " + i + " using offer(): " + queue.offer(i));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Adding 1 using add(): true
Adding 1 using offer(): true
Adding 2 using add(): true
Adding 2 using offer(): true
Capacity reached. Cannot add 3 using add()
Adding 3 using offer(): false
```

- This code creates a Queue with a capacity of 2 using a LinkedList and
  adds elements 1 to 3 to the queue.
- It shows the difference between the add and offer methods when
  the queue reaches its capacity.
- The **add()** method *throws an exception* when the capacity is exceeded,
  while the **offer()** method *returns false in such cases*.