# Difference between offer() and add() in priority queue in java?

Tags: java

Why two functions for doing same thing?

Description provided in java api docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html is same.

Comment: There is another thread on StackOverFlow with similar query : [Difference between add and offer method][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703984/what-is-the-difference-between-the-add-and-offer-methods-in-a-queue

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The two functions come from two different interfaces that `PriorityQueue` implements:

- `add()` comes from `Collection`.
- `offer()` comes from `Queue`.

For a capacity-constrained queue, the difference is that `add()` always returns `true` and throws an exception if it can't add the element, whereas `offer()` is allowed to return `false` if it can't add the element.

However, this doesn't apply to `PriorityQueue`; the two functions are synonymous.

Comment: What do mean by capacity constrained queue?

Comment: @user7098526 Some queue implementations may have fixed capacity, for e.g. ArrayBlockingQueue. The use case may be some buffer that will simply reject add request if it's full already - kinda a protection of OOO.