# Should Queue#offer() be preferred over Queue#add()? Why?

Tags: java, queue

`offer()` returns `boolean` whereas `add()` throws `Exception` if there are no elements in the `Queue`. So, which one should be used in general and what are the advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: Well, throwing an exception is expensive.  That would be one reason to prefer the other method.  In general though I'd say "depends on your requirements."

Comment: Thanks! Any example "requirement"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the difference is in the contract, that when element can not be added to collection the add method throws an exception and offer doesn't.

From: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29

> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason
>   other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an
>   exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant
>   that a collection always contains the specified element after this
>   call returns. From:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer%28E%29

> Inserts the specified element into this queue, if possible. When using
>   queues that may impose insertion restrictions (for example capacity
>   bounds), method offer is generally preferable to method
>   Collection.add(E), which can fail to insert an element only by
>   throwing an exception.

Source:- [What is the difference between the add and offer methods in a Queue in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703984/what-is-the-difference-between-the-add-and-offer-methods-in-a-queue-in-java)

Comment: This question is not about 'differences' between those methods.